# Concat HashSet<String> and IList<String>

Tags: c#

I have a hash set as :

```
HashSet<String> hash ;
```

and a list as:

```
IList<String> names = new List<String>(){"ABC","DEF"};
```

I want to concat hash and names; then store the result in same variable i.e. hash.

What is the best approach to do this since I have arround 10k records to store in HashSet?

Comment: "then store the result in hash", do you mean another `HashSet<string>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx):

> Modifies the current HashSet object to contain all elements that are present in itself, the specified collection, or both.

```
hash.UnionWith(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var name in names)
    hash.Add(name);
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted as it will actually work... though it could do with an explanation.

Comment: I also don't see what's wrong with a simple `foreach`. `UnionWith` does basically the same (it just adds a `null` check).